# Dynamic ItemRenderer for Flex Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, itemrenderer

I have DataGrid with Dynamic Columns. The columns will contain ItemRendrer. I'm not familiar with dynamically adding ItemRenderer.
My code is:

```
var column:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
column.headerText = item;
column.width=150;
column.dataField=item;
column.itemRenderer = WorkNatureRenderer ;
cols.push(column);
```

`WorkNatureRenderer` is a mxml component.(`Hbox` containing `TextInput` and `Button`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">

    <s:TextInput/>
    <s:Button/>

</mx:HBox>
```

But when I add this I got an Error `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type mx.core:IFactory.`

Any examples Or Links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
myList.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(WorkNatureRenderer);
```

i guess this will help u...IM NOT SURE..

Comment: Thank you for quick reply..It seems working.. small mistake I was trying using `WorkNatureRenderer as ClassFactory` which was not working..

Comment: @M.S.Nayak hey tats wokay Man...wen it works let me know..This was a unique requirement.. Im curious to work for the same.. cya!:-)