# How to assign a item render dynamically in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to change a list's item render with code like this:

```
booklist.itemRenderer = BookItemRender;
```

BookItemRender is a subclass of s:ItemRenderer.

It report error:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type
```

How to correctly specify a itemRender in code?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/8518206/842112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a ClassFactory instance for this:

```
booklist.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(BookItemRender);
```